# Rearranging Elements in Arrays in C++

Tags: c++

I am creating a program that has a user enter in the number of elements they want to input in the array, then the user enters that number of values. The program is supposed to output the original indexes of the array, and then also output an arrangement were the 1st and last element of the array trade places. For example if the user entered in the elements, 1 2 3 4, the output would display that and 4 2 3 1. Any tips? My program currently rearranges all the elements so that it outputs 3 4 1 2.

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void swapfrontback(int a[], int n);//function declaration
int main()
{

    int a[10], i, n;
    cout << "enter size" << endl; //size of array
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 0)
    {
        cout << "Array is empty!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "enter elements" << endl;//input the array elements by user
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            cin >> a[i];
        }
    }
    swapfrontback(a, n);//calling swap function
    return 0;
}
void swapfrontback(int a[], int n)//function defintion
{
    int i, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
    {
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[n / 2 + i];
        a[n / 2 + i] = temp;
    }

    cout << "swapping array is" << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you write a swap function for two numbers?  `void swap(int& first, int& second)`. Then, how do you find the first and last elements of your array?  `arr[0]` and `arr[???]`?

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is [the debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger). With a debugger you can execute the program at your speed and watch what the program really does as it does it. When you see the program doing something unexpected like taking the wrong path, computing the wrong number, etc... you've probably found a bug. Very humbling, the debugger.

Comment: Side note: If `n` is not guaranteed to be ten or less the program is going to have a very rough time.

Comment: `n / 2 + i` is not the index that you want to swap. You wanted to swap the last index with the first. The last index is `n-1`

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to **correct** the *index* from  **[n / 2 + i]**  to  **[n - i-1]**

Corrected Code here:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void swapfrontback(int a[], int n);//function declaration
int main()
{

    int a[10], i, n;
    cout << "enter size" << endl; //size of array
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 0)
    {
        cout << "Array is empty!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "enter elements" << endl;//input the array elements by user
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            cin >> a[i];
        }
    }
    swapfrontback(a, n);//calling swap function
    return 0;
}
void swapfrontback(int a[], int n)//function defintion
{
    int i, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
    {
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[n - i-1];
        a[n - i-1] = temp;
    }

    cout << "swapping array is" << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void swapfrontback(int a[], int n);//function declaration
void swap(int [],int);
int main(){
    int a[10], i, n;
    cout << "enter size" << endl; //size of array
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 0)
        cout << "Array is empty!\n";
    else{
        cout << "enter elements" << endl;//input the array elements by user
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cin >> a[i];
    }
    //Will swap all elements
    swapfrontback(a, n);//calling swap function
    //Will swap only first ans last
    swap(a,n);
    return 0;
}
//Will swap all elements
void swapfrontback(int a[], int n){
    int i, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++){
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[n-i-1];
        a[n-i-1] = temp;
    }
    cout << "swapping array is" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << a[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
//Swaps only first and last
void swap(int arr[],int n){
    int temp=arr[0];
    arr[0]=arr[n-1];
    arr[n-1]=temp;
}
```

Comment: `a[i] = a[n / 2 + i]; a[n / 2 + i] = temp;` in these two statements u are comiting mistake if u want to swap all the elements in that fashion swap element at index `n-i-1` and `i` .